# Visual Studio - Keeping command window open

Tags: c#, debugging, process.start

So I'm debugging a C# program in Visual Studio, and it launches a command window for `Process.Start`.

I want to keep this window open - however the method I tried - doing a `Console.Readline();` didn't work.

Is there a standard way to keep a console window open so that I can see what happens when the program executes? It would be very helpful for debugging

Comment: All I can tell you that this works well in C++.

Comment: For `Process.Start` - is this asynchronous from the rest of the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with CMD.EXE and pass your program as argument

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/K \"dir\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Visual Studio, I am not sure if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> is what you are looking for... this keeps the console active.